# Можно ли программировать на MacBook 12 (2017 года)

Tags: swift, macbook

всем! 
Решил что моим первым языком программирования будет swift, до этого программированием не занимался.Теперь осталось только выбрать ноутбук.Решил что это будет MacBook 12 дюймов,так как приходиться много кочевать с одного места на другое,и нужен лёгкий ноутбук. Но после просмотров многочисленных обзоров на Ютубе, у меня начались сомнение на счёт этого устройства. Можно ли на нём программировать на swift? (Хочу взять версию с Intel Core i5 7Y54) 
Заранее спасибо за ответы :)

Comment: Ну, если к нему подключить внешние монитор 24 дюйма и клавиатуру, то почему бы нет?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не относится непосредственно к программированию, а выбор ноутбука — вещь очень субъективная

Comment: Все же лучше будет взять  MBP 13. По габаритам, массе и цене не на много больше, но Xcode ворочает отлично и вполне комфортно работать. Хотя есть люди, которым и на Air 11 комфортно. Все относительно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно.
Разумеется работать со Storyboard на таком размере экрана - мучение.
У вас есть 2 опции:

- Иметь на работе или дома (где вы будете проводить большую часть
  работы) внешний монитор от 24'' и любую клавиатуру и мышь
- И более простая опция - избегайте использования Storyboard и xib в
  работе, делайте все кодом.